# Three-Way ANOVA interpretation with significance in all combinations of factors!

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

I did the Three-Way ANOVA test and A, B, C, AB, B*C, A*C, A*B*C are all significant. Now,

1. What can I tell based on this results?
2. Is it valid to say for example A*B is significant? Or the fact that A*B*C is significant, makes it wrong to say A*B is significant?
3. Should/Can I do Two-way ANOVA even though I have 3 factors?

Answer (score 1):

The three-way ANOVA is used to determine if there is an interaction effect (independent variables interact if the effect of one of the variables differs depending on the level of the other variable) between three independent variables on a continuous dependent variable.

Therefore you would only be interested in the significance value of A*B*C. If it is significant, you would report that there is a 3-way interaction which means that at least one of the 2-way interactions changes across the third independent variable. If A*B*C is not significant, it would be better to apply 2-way ANOVA.

Because when interaction effects are present, it means that interpretation of the main effects or underlying lower level interactions is incomplete or misleading. Hence the significances of A, B, C, A*B, B*C, A*C are not important.